# In Flask, is it there a way to run some code before every view?

Tags: python, flask

I want to clean the session flash with get_flashed_messages(), before the code of every view gets executed. That's because flash is persistent in the session, which is very unfortunate (if the flashed messages are not printed in the authentication procedure, for example, they get all printed at once in the first page that uses the layout).

So, I wanted to run code before every view in the application to clean the session flashed messages.

Functions like before_request or before_app_request won't do it right, because they get executed many times during the request (they are executed for every template or static file being uploaded), and this erases the messages which are flashed inside the view code (I just want to erase the persisted messages from other views, before the current view starts running).

Simply, I want some code to run once, and only once, before every view function is called.

Is this possible in Flask?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Source : https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/1.1.x/templating/

To inject new variables automatically into the context of a template, context processors exist in Flask. Context processors run before the template is rendered and have the ability to inject new values into the template context. A context processor is a function that returns a dictionary. The keys and values of this dictionary are then merged with the template context, for all templates in the app:

```
@app.context_processor
def inject_user():
    return dict(user=g.user)
```

The context processor above makes a variable called user available in the template with the value of g.user. This example is not very interesting because g is available in templates anyways, but it gives an idea how this works.

Variables are not limited to values; a context processor can also make functions available to templates (since Python allows passing around functions):

```
@app.context_processor
def utility_processor():
    def format_price(amount, currency=u'€'):
        return u'{0:.2f}{1}'.format(amount, currency)
    return dict(format_price=format_price)
```

The context processor above makes the format_price function available to all templates:

```
{{ format_price(0.33) }}
```

Comment: This happened to be useful for another thing I was doing with before_request. Context processors seem better for that use case.

Answer (score 1):

If use the `before_request` hook on the blueprint? This should can only effect on the blueprint views.

> before_request(f)
>   Like Flask.before_request() but for a blueprint. This function is only executed >before each request that is handled by a function of that blueprint.

Refer: https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/1.1.x/api/?highlight=before_request#flask.Blueprint.before_request

**UPDATE**

I try some code as follows:

app.py

```
from flask import Flask
from app.ext import db, login_manager

def create_app():
    app = Flask(__name__)
    app.config.from_object(config)
    db.init_app(app)
    login_manager.init_app(app)
    # blueprints
    register_blueprints('app.views', app)
    return app
```

views/myview.py

```
from flask import (
    Blueprint, render_template,
    flash, get_flashed_messages
)
from flask_login import login_required

bp = Blueprint('myview', __name__, url_prefix='/myview')


@bp.before_request
def before_func():
    print(get_flashed_messages())
    print('---------------')


@bp.route('/index', methods=['GET'])
@login_required
def index():
    flash('Now in index')
    return render_template('index.html')


@bp.route('/home', methods=['GET'])
@login_required
def home():
    flash('Now in home')
    return render_template('home.html')
```

When I run the code.  every request in `myview` execute `before_func` only once. So, Is this what you want?

Comment: I have tried that. It is nonetheless called multiple times. I don't know why, but flask makes a lot of requests to the same blueprint before returning the view. I think it is at least partly because of flask_login. Therefore I needed something that runs once and only once for every view, not request.

Answer (score 0):

If it is a common functionality, you can write a decorator using `wraps` from `functools`. Make sure to write the decorator below the app.route decorator.

Comment: Hi! Well, that would work... But I would have to write the decorator above every single view in the platform. I was looking for a hook more like before_request.